# Session times out although the user has been typing in the form

Tags: asp.net, session

In my asp.net web application, the session is set to its default timeout value. As far as I understand, the timeout starts to count the minutes as soon as the application is idle and no action is done on it. However, when i open up a form and start filling it, if I take longer than 20 minutes to fill up the form then when i press "Save" the application logs out. I'm not inactive, but actually i'm filling up data in the form, so I don't want the session to timeout.

Is there a way to let the session only start counting the time when there is no action at all and let it "sense" the typing of the user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a "heartbeat". There are a number of ways of achieving this - the easiest will depend on what other assets you already have in your page - jQuery, AJAX controls, whatever.

The basic premise is that it sends, in the background, a request to the server effectively saying "I am still here" to the server to stop the timeout from happening. Ideally your solution should be checking for onkeypress in the javascript to ensure a user is there and filling in the form.

A search for "heartbeat form filling javascript asp.net" leads to a few sample ideas.